# Android HTTPS get request hangs on response = client.execute(request);

Tags: android, https

I am developing an android application in which I have to post a form of date to HTTPs.

First I try to connect to the page and execute a get request but the app is being hanged on:

`response = client.execute(request);`.

No error messages in LogCat or console.

**Is this the right way to do this, is there a better way to do it?**.

```
HttpURLConnection http = null;
    String urlStr = "https://www.hilan.co.il/";
    URL url;
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {        
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(urlStr));
            response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            if (resEntity != null) {    
                WebView responseText=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                responseText.loadData(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity),"text/html", "UTF-8");
            }
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Why are you doing `findViewById()` while posting request?

Comment: I just need to disply the page in my app so i can see the result.

Comment: display the page? What do you mean by Page in Android?

Comment: I mean the entity of the response a html page.

Comment: If you have to POST a form with data (with parameters) then why do you use a GET request without parameters?

Comment: Just for testing I am a newbe i first want to check if the code works this way. Please any suggestions?

Comment: That makes no sence. If you want to implement POST then do not test with GET. Moreover I tried your url in a browser on the PC and there a timeout is reported.

Comment: Its mistaken should be hilanet.co.il

Comment: Ok then show me how to implement post?

Comment: There are many examples on this site using HttpClient and HttpPost to post to a website. Just search this site for it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that the url is mistaken should be https://www.hilanet.co.il.